# indian rupee symbol UnicodeEncodeError while uploading file to s3 using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3

I have scraped some data from a website for my assignment. It consists of Indian rupee character - "₹". The data when I'm trying to save into CSV file in utf-8 characters on local machine using pandas, it is saving effortlessly. The same file, I have changed the delimiters and tried to save the file to s3 using pandas, but it gave "UnicodeEncodeError" error. I'm scraping the web page using scrapy framework.

Earlier I was trying to save the file in Latin-1 i.e. "ISO-8859-1" formatting and hence changed to "utf-8" but the same error is occurring. I'm using pythn 3.7 for the development.

Below code used for saving on the local machine which is working:

```
result_df.to_csv(filename+str2+'.csv',index=False)
```

Below code is used to save the file to S3:

```
search_df.to_csv('s3://my-bucket/folder_path/filename_str2.csv',encoding = 'utf-8',line_terminator='^',sep='~',index=False)
```

Below is the error while saving the file to S3:

```
2019-10-29 19:24:27 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <function Spider.close at 0x0000019CD3B1AA60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydispatch\robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 94, in close
    return closed(reason)
  File "C:\local_path\spiders\Pduct_Scrape.py", line 430, in closed
    search_df.to_csv('s3://my-bucket/folder_path/filename_str2.csv',encoding = 'utf-8',line_terminator='^',sep='~',index=False)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3020, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 172, in save
    self._save()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 288, in _save
    self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 315, in _save_chunk
    self.cols, self.writer)
  File "pandas/_libs/writers.pyx", line 75, in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 2661: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am very new to this StackOverflow platform and please let me know if more information is to be presented.

Comment: Try encoding='utf8' instead of encoding='utf-8'

Comment: @GSazheniuk This trick didn't work. :(
Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The error gives an evidence that the code tries to encode the `filename_str2.csv` file in cp1252. From your stack trace:

...
File "C:\local_path\spiders\Pduct_Scrape.py", line 430, in closed
  
    search_df.to_csv('s3://my-bucket/folder_path/ **filename_str2.csv** ',...
...
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\encodings\ **cp1252.py** ", line 19, in encode

The reason I do not know, because you explicitely ask for an `utf-8` encoding. But as the codecs page in the Python Standard Library reference says that the canonical name for utf8 is `utf_8` (notice the underline instead of minus sign) and does not list `utf-8` in allowed aliases, I would first try to use `utf_8`. If it still uses cp1252, then you will have to give the exact versions of Python and pandas that you are using.

Comment: I know it is not a true answer but it is too long for a comment. If OP says that it was not helpful, I will delete it.

Comment: That's a good catch @Serge Ballesta. But how can I configure python to consider 'utf-8' encoding instead of cp1252 while uploading?
Also, the utf_8 did not work for me either.